# widgetTests console output: What does the number after the `~` refer to?

Tags: flutter-test, widget-test-flutter

We're running `widgetTests` and I'm seeing output like

```
        :
00:08 +76: /Users/<path>/sliver_app_bar_test.dart: <test description>
00:08 +77 ~1: /Users/<path>/sliver_app_bar_test.dart: <test description>
00:08 +78 ~2: /Users/<path>/sliver_app_bar_test.dart: <test description>
00:08 +79 ~3: /Users/<path>/sliver_app_bar_test.dart: <test description>
00:08 +80 ~3: /Users/<path>/sliver_app_bar_test.dart: <test description>
        :
00:33 +386 ~3: All tests passed!
```

The number after the `+` is the test counter. What's the number after the `~` refer to?

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of skipped tests.